# Tensorflow: DropoutWrapper leads to different output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I build a LSTM like:

```
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * 3, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Then i train the model, and save variables.
The next time i load saved variables and skip training, it gives me a different prediction.

If i change the `output_keep_prob` to 1, this model can always show me the same prediction, but if the `output_keep_prob` is less than 1, like 0.5, this model shows me different prediction every time.

So i guess if the `DropoutWrapper` leads to different output?
If so, how can i solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `seed` keyword argument to `DropoutWrapper(...)`:

```
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.5, seed=42)
```

See the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cell_wrappers__rnncells_that_wrap_other_rnncells_#DropoutWrapper) for `DropoutWrapper.__init__`

Comment: Since it's a random integer, does every `seed` correspond to a different way of dropout?

Comment: If so, should i try different `seed` to get an optimized result? It seems to be a large project to try all random integers...

Comment: Hey @nickzxd and @kempy! I'm unable to get consistent results after setting `seed` in the `DropoutWrapper`. Is anything else needed?

Answer (score 1):

Dropout will randomly activate a subset of your net, and is used during training for regularization. Because you've hardcoded dropout as 0.5, it means every time you run the net half your nodes will be randomly silenced, thus producing a different and random result.

You can sanity check this is what's happening by setting a seed, so that the same nodes will be 'randomly' silenced by dropout each time. However, what you probably want to do is make dropout a placeholder so that you can set it to 1.0 (ie keep all the nodes) during test time, which will produce the same output for each input deterministically.